# Shortcut for UnitTest in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

i have my view, which are presenting that:
[image]

You can see, that I have TestMethod grouping by `TestCategory` and more - you can see, that i have cursor on the red arrow. I know that i can run my test (`Can_view_my_Context()`) by `Ctrl + R, Ctrl + T`. Now I want to start All testUnit, which are in the same category, by a shortcut or other fast way and it's my qustion: what's that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not supported.  You can see the options by searching for "TestExplorer." in Keyboard shortcuts (Tools -> Customize -> Keyboard...).
Probably the best choice for using Categories would be to Group By traits and run the Category you want and then use Ctrl R,L to RepeatLastRun.
The other option that might get you close enough is to click on the class name and use Ctrl+R,T to run everything in the class.
Unfortunately, the Test Explorer just isn't very good.

Comment: Thanks you for answer. What explorer for unit test are you preferer or recommend??

Comment: You can use the Resharper runner, but I don't know that it will address your issue.  It's not free, but it adds a lot of value elsewhere.  Otherwise, you may be stuck running an external runner and that will probably be more disruptive.  I generally just use the built-in runner and use Ctrl+R,A to run all tests unless I'm debugging a particular test.  This keeps me from forgetting to run some test before a checkin.